# Diagonalizable matrix by polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $A$ to be a matrix of $3 \times 3$.

$1.$ If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)$, then the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ is $(t-1)(t-4)(t-9)$ ?

$2.$ If the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$ is $(t-1)(t-4)(t-9)$, then $A$ is diagonalizable ?

Any hints on how to start solving this kind of problems?

Comment: $A$ is diagonalizable then there is an invertibale matrix $P$ such that $A= PBP^{-1}$  and $B$ is diagonal. now $A^2 = PBP^{-1}  PBP^{-1}$

Comment: Each distinct eigenvalue (or characteristic value, root of characteristic equation) of a matrix will have at least one linearly independent eigenvector.  So if there are three distinct eigenvalues, then a $3\times 3$ matrix will have a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @hardmath so from what I understand that means that the second assumption is true? what about the first assumption? how can I tell what is the minimum polynomial of the square of $A$ ?

Comment: There is the fact that the roots (eigenvalues) of $A$ are distinct ($1,2,3$), and that the squares of these roots (see the computation by @Kavim) are the eigenvalues of $A^2$, and they remain distinct.  So the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $A^2$ are identical with the characteristic polynomials of these respective matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly $A^2$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, hence the minimal polynomial is of degree at most $3$. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ will be eigen value of $A^2$. Thus in your case, the eigen values of $A^2$ are $1,4,9$. All these have to be roots of minimal polynomial of $A^2$. Thus your minimal polynomial will be......

Again using the size of $A^2$ and the fact that it has three distinct eigen values, the corresponding eigen vectors will be linearly independent, hence $A^2$ is diagonlizable.

Comment: Thanks I got the second one, but about the first one. from what I understand, then the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ is really $(t-1)(t-4)(t-9)$ right? just making sure I'm not misunderstand you

Comment: @DanRevah yes because on one hand degree is "at most" $3$ and on the other hand we have three distinct roots.